# Using stringstream in place of string? - C++

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I've been given a homework assignment to write a program in C++, but we're not allowed to use the string class. However, we are allowed to use the [iostream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostream) library, including stringstream. I was thinking of using stringstream where I would have used string for building my classes, returning from functions, etc.

Does this sound like a good idea to you? Any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: The only way to get stuff out of a stringstream is to convert it to a string.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer, since we don't know what was the reason you're not allowed to use the string class. Was the point of the assignment to find a clever way to use another standard class instead of the string? Or were you supposed to implement your own string class?

Comment: It's an assignment about polymorphism. We're building a shop database which stores a list of products and shopping baskets.They're just being stingy by not letting us use strings. I think they expect us to use char* or some other way of storing an array of chars. But we're free to figure out other creative solutions.

Comment: @workmad3 - Can't I send it directly to cout? or to a char or char[] or another stringstream?

Comment: Hopefully you only have to deal with ASCII characters. Think about wrapping vector<char> (or whatever you end up choosing) in your own string class

Answer (score 10):

You could also use vector<char>. It's a good alternative to string. As Scott Meyers says in his "Effective STL" book:

> Third, consider using a vector<char>
>   instead of a string, vector
>   implementations are not allowed to be
>   reference counted, so hidden
>   multithreading performance issues fail
>   to arise. Of course, you forgo
>   string's fancy member functions if you
>   switch to vector<char>, but most of
>   that functionality is available
>   through STL algorithms anyway, so
>   you're-not so much giving up
>   functionality as you are trading one
>   syntax for another.

I think the main problems that could arise from using stringstream are that it's not strictly a container. I'm not sure if it is possible to use algorithms and other regular STL stuff with streams.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is a shop database without strings, you could just simply use an enum.

```
enum {
     Prod1,
     Prod2,
     Prod3
};
```

Which means you can just pass integers around as identifiers and then just have a print function with a switch statement.

```
void PrintProd(int product) {
    switch(product) {
         case Prod1: 
              cout << "Product 1" << endl;
              break;
         case Prod2:
              cout << "Product 2" << endl;
              break;
     // etc.
     }
}
```

This allows you to bypass a lot of trouble. If you don't mind dealing with the heap, a vector of char* allocating the product names with the id's being the index into the vector would work too.